# How to make the list loop working in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

To autofill the login page, I have created a code to direct the python to try different usernames from an external list, until the correct one is found. But when I run the code, it only tries the first username from the list, and then stops. i.e it doesn't try the remaining username values. Kindly help me to make the script work as I want. Thank you.

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

webdriver.get("https://examplewebsite.com/login/index.php")


password = webdriver.find_element_by_id("password")
password.send_keys("Helloworld1@")

username = webdriver.find_element_by_id("username")
usernamefile = open("list.txt", "r")


for i in usernamefile:
        username.send_keys(i)
        submit = webdriver.find_element_by_id("loginbtn")
        submit.submit()
```

Edit: This is the error python shows then. I don't know how to fix it.

```
File "C:\Users\Ranjhaaa\Desktop\test.py", line 23, in <module>
    username.send_keys(i)
  File "C:\Users\Ranjhaaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\Users\Ranjhaaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Ranjhaaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Ranjhaaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
```

Comment: stack keep reference to elements on current page and when you click button `submit` then it loads new page and all references are lost - and this gives your error message. After every reloading you would have to use again `find_element_by_id` to get access to field `password` and `username` - so you would have to do it inside `for i in usernamefile:`

Comment: @furas can you please show these additions in the original code? Actually being new to coding, I'm a little confused as to how and where to make these useful changes suggested by you. Thank you

Comment: I added it as answer belowe

Comment: so you can mark my answer as accepted and later you can upvote it.

Comment: @furas Your answer has been marked as accepted, and it will be upvoted soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selenium` keeps your object `password` and `username` as reference to elements on current page and when you click button `submit` then it loads new page and all references are lost - and this gives your error message `"element is not attached to the page document"`.

After every reloading page you have to use again `find_element_by_id` to get access to field `password` and `username` - so you would have to do it inside `for`-loop

```
usernamefile = open("list.txt", "r")

for i in usernamefile:
    password = webdriver.find_element_by_id("password")
    password.send_keys("Helloworld1@")

    username = webdriver.find_element_by_id("username")
    username.send_keys(i)

    submit = webdriver.find_element_by_id("loginbtn")
    submit.submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever a user name got wrong it takes some time to load the next page if its giving you not find element types error that's mean you just have to use some time sleep to the last of the code to do it right

Comment: I'm new to coding. Can you please illustrate your suggestion by making corrections in the code? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

usernamefile = open("list.txt", "r")


for i in usernamefile:
     webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

     webdriver.get("https://examplewebsite.com/login/index.php")

     username = webdriver.find_element_by_id("username")

     password = webdriver.find_element_by_id("password")
     password.send_keys("Helloworld1@")
   
     username.send_keys(i)
     submit = webdriver.find_element_by_id("loginbtn")
     submit.submit()
     driver.quit()
```

if the username is correct and it logins then the password and username fields are no longer available. You can quit driver and start again in the loop

Answer (score 0):

from selenium import webdriver

file_path = "your executable path for chromedriver"

Usernames = open("list.txt", "r")

for i in Usernames:
browser = webdriver.Chrome(file_path)

```
 browser.get("https://examplewebsite.com/login/index.php")

 username = webdriver.find_element_by_id("username")
 username.send_keys(i)
 password = webdriver.find_element_by_id("password")
 password.send_keys("Helloworld1@")

 
 submit = webdriver.find_element_by_id("loginbtn")
 submit.submit() 
 # then close the driver and start again the loop
 browser.close()
 # also you can use the refresh function
```